# Why is ctags ignoring function?

Tags: ctags

I am running ctags on [this file](https://github.com/accesio/AIOUSB/blob/master/AIOUSB/lib/AIOContinuousBuffer.c) and it is ignoring the `get_read_pos()` function.  This is what I'm doing:

```
$ ctags AIOContinuousBuffer.c
$ grep get_read_pos tags || echo Not Found
Not Found
```

Shouldn't it find the function?  I am running on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The file is being parsed as C. If you use `--language-force=C++` the function you are referring to appears in the output tags file. And, as far as I understand, `namespace` is still processed by the C parser, but since it is not a contextual language its parentheses are skipped. Note that ctags will not understand the `#ifdef __cplusplus` to ignore the name space declaration.

Comment: Weird.  It works but I don't understand why it recognizes some functions but not all.  If I remove the namespace statement then I don't need to force it to C++ but I still don't understand why it half-works.